# PHP / jQuery Ajax / load xml within Ajax Processing Page

Tags: php, jquery, xml, ajax

I'm stuck with some PHP Code that's called from a jQuery.Ajax call.

Basic code is this:

process.php:

```
$video_id = "u-KoTOhbn30";
$url = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/". $video_id;
$doc = simplexml_load_file($url);
$title = $doc->title;
// [sudo] Enter title into database //
```

Now, when I visit http://www.mydomain.com/process.php it works perfectly.

In my homepage is:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "process.php",
  data: dataString,
  success: function() {
     // do something
    });
  }
 });
```

Now, when the process.php gets called within this ajax process...nothing happens? it fails / ignores it.  So how can I do it?? how can I read in an XML file within a page being called by Ajax?

Edit: Just to clarify... the Ajax call does process my page, its just that the $doc = simplexml_load_file($url); call doesn't work  If i view the page manually simplexml works.  When it's called via ajax it does nothing

Many thanks in advance

Comment: You say when you visit the page it works perfectly... how are you passing the data string to it if you're calling it directly? Are you putting in get variables into the querystring? And as such, does this mean that you're using `$_GET` in your php code? If so, your POST won't work for ajax. The best thing to do in this case is to use firebug to see what the response from the page is.

Comment: My problem is simply that $doc = simplexml_load_file($url); does NOT function when called via ajax.  everything else works, i stripped out the success function above as it wasn't relative to the question.  I added steps in my process.php to write out error to my database etc.  Basically all steps work.  The only thing that does NOT work is $doc = simplexml_load_file($url);.  It's gotta be something to do with DOM  as I tried a similar function to process the xml via a dom call and that failed too

Comment: do u by any chance use the base href TAG anywhere?

Comment: nope :-/ I've changed my code about and called the procedure on the page being browsed using a jquery getjson call, then processing the process via ajax only after getjson has finished (so i can pass data into the ajax call)

Answer (score 1):

Add a parameter to success function to get returned data.

```
success: function(data) {
   alert(data); // returned content is stored in data and it is alerted here.
   // do something
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I wasn't clear enough about the problem.

$doc = simplexml_load_file($url); does NOT work when called from my process page... I need it to so I can process the video title within my process page

Comment: There is no error... it just doesn't return anything... It's like nothing happens. The processing page itself completes and works... all apart from $doc = simplexml_load_file($url);